# MVC futures async with a custom delegate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I'm trying to use async from the asp.net mvc futures, using my own async delegate. Haven't figured out how to make it work. Here's the code:

```
    public delegate String GetString();
    public String getHello() { return "Hello"; }

    public IAsyncResult BeginHello(AsyncCallback cb, Object state)
    {
        GetString dlgt = getHello; 
        return dlgt.BeginInvoke(cb, state);
    }

    public ActionResult EndHello(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

In EndHello, asyncResult.IsCompleted=True, but asyncResult.AsyncState==null. I expected to have AsyncState=="Hello".

What am I missing?

Also, does it even make sense to arrange it this way? Or does this cause it to use the same thread pool anyway? Basically my thought was to put a datareader in my asynchronous function, thinking that I could loop through the reader populating a collection of objects and only return when they're done.  Is it better to use BeginExecuteReader and populate the objects on the main thread?

EDIT: To anyone reading this later, this is in fact the wrong way to do it, and won't help you at all. BeginExecuteReader is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not get Hello in AsyncState.

Hello will be returned when you do an EndInvoke().

e.g.
Here's the code you should be using:

```
public String EndHello(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    
{        
    GetString getStringDel = (asyncResult as AsyncResult).AsyncDelegate as GetString;
    return getStringDel.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
}
```

You can refer to:

MSDN link [Calling Synchronous Methods Asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx)

SO answer to [What is AsyncCallback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047662/what-is-asynccallback/1047677#1047677)

Comment: Thanks! Now I just need to do some testing with wcat and see if this is actually a good idea :)