# What is a callback?

Tags: c#, callback

What's a callback and how is it implemented in C#?

Comment: Are you referring to ASP.Net callbacks or delegate callback parameters?

Comment: It could mean a number of things - in what context have you heard it?

Comment: I think he is talking about an Async. Callback

Comment: -1 The question is unclear(not enough details).

Comment: if you are looking for AsyncCallBack, look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047662/what-is-asynccallback

Answer (score 167, accepted):

> In [computer programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming), a callback is [executable code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_code) that is passed as an [argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(computer_science)) to other code.
>
> —[Wikipedia: Callback (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_science%29)

C# has [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/index) for that purpose. They are heavily used with [events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/), as an event can automatically invoke a number of attached delegates (event handlers).

Comment: actually a callback is a pointer to executable code that is passed as an argument to other code... the page needs a review

Comment: @G_G: There is nothing that says it has to be a pointer. It usually is because the data segment is not executable, but that's technically an implementation detail.

Comment: Joey: u are right it's an implementation detail but even the callback is implementation detail. You could rewrite your code without usino a single callback. It's like 'while' vs 'for'.

Answer (score 1659):

I just met you,
And this is crazy,
But here's my number (delegate),
So if something happens (event),
Call me, maybe (callback)?

Comment: Totally cool explanation. I will use this explanation whenever someone asks, hope I can get rights to use it?

Comment: @Nick: lol, go ahead. Noting it for my next intro to code class.

Comment: +1: Love it. It ruins the song, but that should read `But here's my number and the instructions for using a specific type of phone (delegate)'

Comment: Note that teaching delegate to other people with that explanation only works with a good choreography :)

Comment: Found this from a Programmer Humor post lol

Answer (score 123):

A callback is a function that will be called when a process is done executing a specific task.

The usage of a callback is usually in asynchronous logic.

To create a callback in C#, you need to store a function address inside a variable. This is achieved using a `delegate` or the new lambda semantic `Func` or `Action`.

```
    public delegate void WorkCompletedCallBack(string result);

    public void DoWork(WorkCompletedCallBack callback)
    {
        callback("Hello world");
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        WorkCompletedCallBack callback = TestCallBack; // Notice that I am referencing a method without its parameter
        DoWork(callback);
    }

    public void TestCallBack(string result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

In today C#, this could be done using lambda like:

```
    public void DoWork(Action<string> callback)
    {
        callback("Hello world");
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        DoWork((result) => Console.WriteLine(result));
        DoWork(Console.WriteLine); // This also works
    }
```

Answer (score 57):

## Definition

> A **callback** is executable code that
>   is passed as an argument to other code.

## Implementation

```
// Parent can Read
public class Parent
{
    public string Read(){ /*reads here*/ };
}

// Child need Info
public class Child
{
    private string information;
    // declare a Delegate
    delegate string GetInfo();
    // use an instance of the declared Delegate
    public GetInfo GetMeInformation;

    public void ObtainInfo()
    {
        // Child will use the Parent capabilities via the Delegate
        information = GetMeInformation();
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
Parent Peter = new Parent();
Child Johny = new Child();

// Tell Johny from where to obtain info
Johny.GetMeInformation = Peter.Read;

Johny.ObtainInfo(); // here Johny 'asks' Peter to read
```

**Links**

- [more details](http://en.csharp-online.net/Delegates_and_Events%E2%80%94Callback_Methods) for C#.

Comment: hi @serhio thank you for your answer. it's still a little murky to me: where exactly is the code passed as an argument to other code Seems to be the adding of the Peter.Read method to the child's delegate?

Comment: @serhio link's dead.

Answer (score 13):

A callback is a function pointer that you pass in to another function.  The function you are calling will 'callback' (execute) the other function when it has completed.

Check out [this](http://www.myelin.co.nz/notes/callbacks/cs-delegates.html) link.

Comment: A callback can be implemented as a delegate to a method, but you could equally say that passing an object that supports a callback method on its interface is a callback.

Comment: Array.Sort(arrayObject); calling obj.CompareTo(anotherObj) on elements of arrayObject is a classic example of callback using Interface (ICompareable) in .Net.

Answer (score 11):

**If you referring to ASP.Net callbacks:**

> In the default model for ASP.NET Web
>   pages, the user interacts with a page
>   and clicks a button or performs some
>   other action that results in a
>   postback. The page and its controls
>   are re-created, the page code runs on
>   the server, and a new version of the
>   page is rendered to the browser.
>   However, in some situations, it is
>   useful to run server code from the
>   client without performing a postback.
>   If the client script in the page is
>   maintaining some state information
>   (for example, local variable values),
>   posting the page and getting a new
>   copy of it destroys that state.
>   Additionally, page postbacks introduce
>   processing overhead that can decrease
>   performance and force the user to wait
>   for the page to be processed and
>   re-created.
>
> To avoid losing client state and not
>   incur the processing overhead of a
>   server roundtrip, you can code an
>   ASP.NET Web page so that it can
>   perform client callbacks. In a client
>   callback, a client-script function
>   sends a request to an ASP.NET Web
>   page. The Web page runs a modified
>   version of its normal life cycle. The
>   page is initiated and its controls and
>   other members are created, and then a
>   specially marked method is invoked.
>   The method performs the processing
>   that you have coded and then returns a
>   value to the browser that can be read
>   by another client script function.
>   Throughout this process, the page is
>   live in the browser.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx

**If you are referring to callbacks in code:**

Callbacks are often delegates to methods that are called when the specific operation has completed or performs a sub-action. You'll often find them in asynchronous operations. It is a programming principle that you can find in almost every coding language.

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Dedication to LightStriker:
Sample Code:

```
class CallBackExample
{
    public delegate void MyNumber();
    public static void CallMeBack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("He/She is calling you.  Pick your phone!:)");
        Console.Read();
    }
    public static void MetYourCrush(MyNumber number)
    {
        int j;
        Console.WriteLine("is she/he interested 0/1?:");
        var i = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(i, out j))
        {
            var interested = (j == 0) ? false : true;
            if (interested)//event
            {
                //call his/her number
                number();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nothing happened! :(");
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyNumber number = Program.CallMeBack;
        Console.WriteLine("You have just met your crush and given your number");
        MetYourCrush(number);
        Console.Read();
        Console.Read();
    }       
}
```

**Code Explanation:**

I created the code to implement the funny explanation provided by LightStriker in the above one of the replies. We are passing delegate (number) to a method (`MetYourCrush`). If the Interested (event) occurs in the method (`MetYourCrush`) then it will call the delegate (number) which was holding the reference of `CallMeBack` method. So, the `CallMeBack` method will be called. Basically, we are passing delegate to call the callback method.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This doesn't adequately answer the question, could you explain what your code is doing, to describe how a callback works, and how it is implemented in C#.

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for your reply.  I created the code to implement the funny explanation provided by LightStriker.    We are passing delegate (number) to a method (MetYourCrush).  If the Interested (event) occurs in the method (MetYourCrush) then it will call the delegate (number) which was holding the reference of CallMeBack method.   So, the CallMeBack method will be called.   Basically, we are passing delegate to call the callback method. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the dictionary definition, but a callback usually refers to a function, which is external to a particular object, being stored and then called upon a specific event.

An example might be when a UI button is created, it stores a reference to a function which performs an action. The action is handled by a different part of the code but when the button is pressed, the callback is called and this invokes the action to perform.

C#, rather than use the term 'callback' uses 'events' and 'delegates' and you can find out more about delegates [here](http://www.myelin.co.nz/notes/callbacks/cs-delegates.html).

Answer (score 2):

callback work steps:

1) we have to implement `ICallbackEventHandler` Interface

2) Register the client script :

```
 String cbReference = Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "arg", "ReceiveServerData", "context");
    String callbackScript = "function UseCallBack(arg, context)" + "{ " + cbReference + ";}";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "UseCallBack", callbackScript, true);
```

1) from UI call Onclient click call javascript function  for EX:- `builpopup(p1,p2,p3...)`

var finalfield= p1,p2,p3;
                `UseCallBack(finalfield, "");`    data from the client passed to server side by using UseCallBack

2)  `public void RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)`  In eventArgument we get the passed data
            //do some server side operation and passed to  "callbackResult"

3)   `GetCallbackResult()`   // using this method data will be passed to client(ReceiveServerData() function) side

callbackResult

4) Get the data at client side:
                     `ReceiveServerData(text)`   , in text server response , we wil get.

Answer (score 2):

## `Callback`  *"call me back"*

**A callback is a function passed as an argument to another function. This technique allows a function to invoke the parameter function argument and even to pass a value back to the caller. A callback function can be designed to run before/after the function has finished and can pass a value.**

> It is a kind of construct where you call a long running function and ask him to call you back once it has finished with can return a parameter result to the caller.

*It's like someone calls you in the middle of your work asking for status and you say "you know what give me 5 min and I will call you back" and at the end you call him to update. If you are a function the caller just added and passed another function that you invoked at the end.*

This can simply be written in `C#` as:

```cs
public void TaskForVinod(Action callback){
    //i am still here working..working

    //i have finished, calling you
    callback();
}

//invoke the fuction with a callback
TaskForVinod(() => { 
    Console.Write("Is it finished"); 
});
```

The one simple example is the iterator function where the return will be multiple times, one can argue that we have `yield` for it:

```cs
public void IterationLoop(int min, int max,Action<int> Callback)
{
    for(int i = min;i<= max;i++)
        Callback(i);
}

//call
IterationLoop(5,50,(x) => { Console.Write(x); }); //will print 5-50 numbers
```

In the code above the function return type is `void` but it has an `Action<int>` callback which is called and sends each item from the loop to the  caller.

The same thing can be done with `if..else` or `try..catch` block as:

```cs
public void TryCatch(Action tryFor,Action catchIt)
{
    try{
        tryFor();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{ex.HResult}] {ex.Message}");
        catchIt();
    }
}
```

And call it as:

```cs
TryCatch(()=>{ 
        int r = 44;
        Console.WriteLine("Throwing Exception");
        throw new Exception("something is wrong here");
    }, ()=>{
        Console.WriteLine("It was a mistake, will not try again");
    });
```

---

However In 2022 we have `Func` & `Action` doing the same, please see the demo code below which shows how this can be be used:

```cs
// Define CallbackDemo
public class CallbackDemo
{
    //simple callback
    public void DoWork(Action callback)
    {
        int a = 5;
        int b = 10;
        
        //i will do th maths and call you back
        int result = a + b;
        
        //callback
        callback(); //execute
        Console.WriteLine($"[The Actual Result is {result}]");
    }
    
    //callback with parameter
    public void DoWork(Action<int> callbackWithParameter)
    {
        int a = 5;
        int b = 10;
        
        //i will do th maths and call you back
        int result = a + b;
        
        //callback
        callbackWithParameter(result); //execute
        Console.WriteLine($"[The Actual Result is {result}]");
    }
    
    //callback with return
    public void DoWork(Func<int> callbackWithReturn)
    {
        int a = 5;
        int b = 10;
        
        //i will do the maths and call you back
        int result = a + b;
        
        //callback
        int c = callbackWithReturn(); //execute
        
        result += c;
        Console.WriteLine($"[The Actual Result is {result}]");
    }
    
    //callback with return and parameter
    public void DoWork(Func<int,int> callabckWithParameterAndReturn)
    {
        int a = 5;
        int b = 10;
        
        //i will do th maths and call you back
        int result = a + b;
        
        //callback
        result += callabckWithParameterAndReturn(result); //execute
        Console.WriteLine($"[The Actual Result is {result}]");
    }
}
```

Finally you can test is as:\

```cs
void Main()
{
    var demo = new CallbackDemo();
    demo.DoWork(()=> { Console.WriteLine("I have finished the work"); });
    demo.DoWork((r)=> { Console.WriteLine($"I have finished the work here is the result {r}"); });
    demo.DoWork(()=> { Console.WriteLine($"This is passed with func"); return 5;});
    demo.DoWork((f)=> { Console.WriteLine($"This is passed with func and result is {f}"); return 10;});
    
}
```