# How can we use callback function in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

How can we use callback function in C#?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what you want? Your question is too generic to answer.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139812/what-is-a-callback)

Comment: Callbacks are used in c++ as a special cases of remote calls that execute as part of a single thread. A callback is issued in the context of a remote call. Any remote procedure defined as part of the same interface as the static callback function can call the callback function.i want to use same cases in c# so i am specifially want to know about this.
So i want to use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is "delegates". For example:

```
public MyClass
{
  public delegate void MyCallback(object sender, string MyArg);

  public string DoSomeWork(string Foo, MyCallback mcb)
  {
    mcb(this, Foo);
    return Foo;
  }
}
```

You can also use delegates to define events. For example, if you wanted an event in MyClass called "OnMyCallback", define it using:

```
...
public event MyCallback OnMyCallback;
...
```

Cheers,
Adam

Answer (score 2):

Reading the questions as: "I want to call a native c++ callback from C#".

You need to create a delegate on the managed/C# side of the boundary.

**C++:**

```
DECLARE_CALLBACK(SampleChannelCallback, void, (void* ptr, uint id, void* data));
```

**C#:**

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate void NativeCallbackDelegate(IntPtr ptr, uint id, IntPtr data);
```

If you are using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to create your native wrapper, then add the follow to your `SwigUtil.h`.

```
#if defined(SWIG)
// Callback declare macro allows for SWIG to automatically construct a macro for a target language for the macros
#define DECLARE_CALLBACK(NAME, RETURNTYPE, PARAMS) typedef void* NAME; %callback_typemap( NAME )
#else
#define DECLARE_CALLBACK(NAME, RETURNTYPE, PARAMS) typedef RETURNTYPE ( NAME ) PARAMS 
#endif
```

As your question was not very clear, I'm going to leave it there. If you want more information then please ask in the comments.

HTH,

Answer (score 0):

Or are you talking about [C# .NET event handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28VS.71%29.aspx) (expanding on the delegates answer)?