# what does callback mean?

Tags: c#, callback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139812/what-is-a-callback)

I'm learning delegates now and I can't understand what "callback" means.

Is it an instance of a delegate type?

Can somebody give a good example of a "callback" implementation?

Comment: You give me your number (delegate), and I'll call you back (callback) when something happens (event).

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras Put it in an answer and you have one upvote for sure :D

Comment: @Nick: Someone closed that question, so no answer, sadly.

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras Put a late answer in a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139812/what-is-a-callback

Comment: @Nick: I guess I can do that.