# How to invoke a method that called the current method in c#

Tags: c#

I want to recall a method from the called method, can i use action for that, or any other solution.

Comment: Be careful! You might be asking for more troubles than you want! What is your use case?

Comment: I think the OP means: A() calls B() and in B() he wants to call A() again.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please edit your question.

Comment: Does he know what A is while in B

Comment: The only solution in A and B case would be to create a new StackTrace() in B and to call the method at frame 1 I think then restart the application because it will crash with stack overflow exception

Comment: `I want to recall a method from the called method` No you don't. Your design is wrong and needs to be fixed.

Comment: function pointers can help i guess?

Comment: It seems you are looking for [CallBack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139812/what-is-a-callback) mechanism?

Comment: But callback should also be meaning full. Tell me this, you want to call some one and they in turn call you back. Is there any use to it and when do you want to stop this and go ahead to get some work done?!

Comment: The situation is bit complicated, dont know wheather its possible to it or not. i want to generalise a function in a method, that method should call the function once again.

Comment: Please provide at least pseudo code of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Actually i want to add retry prompt based on the input by user, if user says to retry then i need to call the function once again, but the code cannot be duplicated , as it is used in many cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some ambiguity in your question use case..

Let us take a simple use case: You want to call some one and they in turn call you back. Is there any use to it and when do you want to stop this and go ahead to get some work done?!

For example following code like what you are expecting will go in infinite recursion and result in `StackOverflowException`

```
class MyClass
{
   public void TargetMethod(Action callback)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Inside TargetMethod");

      callback(); //This call the SourceMethod() and which inturn call TargetMethod() again in infinite recursion.
   }

   public void SourceMethod()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Inside SourceMethod");
      TargetMethod(SourceMethod);       
   }
}

//Calling code
MyClass objMyClass = new MyClass();
objMyClass.SourceMethod();
```

Instead you can use [Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139812/what-is-a-callback) mechanism, so that once you done within the target method, notify another handler method that in turn can do some stuff like logging or updating UI etc., case specific stuff.

```
class MyClass
{
   public void TargetMethod(Action callback)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Inside TargetMethod");

      callback(); //This calls/notify the handler to do some stuff.
   }

   public void SourceMethod()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Inside SourceMethod");
      TargetMethod(CallbackHandler); //Notice here we are calling to a handler which can do some stuff for us.
   }

   public void CallbackHandler()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Inside CallbackHandler");
   }
}
```

This code is just for quick demonstration purpose and you can enhance design further in your implementation.

Hope this provide you some heads-up on why you need to revisit your design..

Comment: Thank you for the reply, hopefully am trying to change the design

Comment: It worked , done with implementation. thanks

Comment: Cool. Mark it as answer if you found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

#### You should not do this in normal situations, your design is probably wrong!

You can use the `CallerInfoAttribute` to get the caller and use reflection to invoke it.

But... that is a lot of work and I think you are not very skilled. Luckily, there is another way!

You can add a parameter of type `MethodInfo`. And let's say `A()` calls `B(MethodInfo)`. Then `A` needs to get its reflected self and pass it into `B`. Then in `B` you can use `MethodInfo.Invoke` to invoke the method.

Well... it turns out that the alternative requires reflection too... So if you are not familiar with reflection, learn more about it first!

If you want to know more about `MethodInfo`, go to here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo(v=vs.110).aspx