# Using Callback function provided by API, but get no results?(C#)

Tags: c#, api, callback

I'm using a API called **WindAPI** which provided the financial data from China markets. This API **provides a method call wsq()** which will provide the **RealTime** price data to user's program **through a callback function**!

I write some simple codes in c#,trying to use this wsq() method, but get no results. I wonder there must be some error in codes, but just can't find it!
I'm new to both C# and programming, so if it's a rookie mistake, don't laugh at me:)

Here's the codes, I'll give as much comments as possible, so you can find the misunderstanding in it quickly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
//-----------------------------
using WAPIWrapperCSharp;  //the namespace in API dll（official provided）
using WindCommon;         //the namespace to process the data formats （official provided）

namespace WSQ2String
{
    class WSQ2StringSample
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("Begin......");
            Console.ReadLine(); 
            //--------------------creat the new API object and log on
            WindAPI w = new WindAPI();
            Console.WriteLine("New API created!");
            w.start();
            Console.WriteLine("API log on!");
            //--------------------request for the realtime data through w.wsq() method
            int errorId = 0;
            ulong reqId = w.wsq(ref errorId, "150195.sz", "rt_date, rt_time, rt_lastest", "", myCallback);
            Console.WriteLine("errorId = {0}", errorId);
            //----adding a control line which will stop the main program and wait for myCallback function to be called
            Console.ReadLine();    //after the data arrived, the test is over, and we press a key to let the main program continue
            w.cancelRequest(reqId);
            w.stop();
            Console.Write("End......");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        //----
        static void myCallback(ulong reqId, WindData wd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("wsq data gotback......");
            //----transfer the official WindData format to String, and output to the screen 
            string s = WindDataMethod.WindDataToString(wd, "wsq");   //the method is in WindCommon namespace 
            Console.Write(s);
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding is that, when I request the data service by using w.wsq(), when the prices change(**that's the event**), myCallback() will be called and export the data on screen!

The reason I add a readline() is to prevent the main program runs too fast, and end before the event(price changing). In that situation, the myCallback() would have no chance to be called!

But when I run the codes, after "errorId = 0" shows, I wait several minutes and still get no results! I confirmed that the price has changed(it usually changed within seconds).

Here is the result I get, and I can't find the reason....(I just type the lines in screen)

```
>>Begin......
>>New API created!
>>API log on!
>>errorId = 0
```

and then the prgram just paused there and nothing more happened!
So I'd be very thankful if someone could explain that to me....

Thank you in advanced!

---

Updated:
According to the comments below, I give the zip files of my solutions.
Also with the API dll and it's source codes.

[My solution files and dll](http://sharesend.com/rueofmh9)

so, anyone help?

Comment: You can use [callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139812/what-is-a-callback) link for better understanding.

Comment: If you can point to the API Souce, then it would be helpful

Comment: @cvraman Thank you for reply! By API Souce, I don't understand what do you mean exactly.(as you know, I am a rookie in programming). Do you mean the whole API dll files? Or just the methods I used?

Comment: @cvraman I give the source codes of the API, is that helpful?

Comment: What exactly is `WindCallback`? And why dont you use it?

Comment: By API Source. I mean, the entire actual source code (or dll) or nuget.
Right now there are too many unknowns for us to be able to arrive at a solution.
Basically if you could post a zip of your visual studio solution, then someone might be able to help.

Comment: After I re-considered the issue, I think maybe there're 2 mistakes in my codes: 1.I declared `myCallback` as private, should it be public? 2.After I use the `w.wsq()` method to request the data, I used the `readline()` for preventing the main program finish too early. Will this also stop the API for calling `myCallback`?  @cvraman

Comment: @SajiRen : Am not sure. I tried running your code but got an exception at the Constructor itself. And the documentation is not in english so I can't read :(
Sorry for not being able to help much.

Comment: @cvraman: Thank you all the same...Letting the API to work also require user to install an application. But that's too much trouble for you helpers, I really understand!  Next time, I'll try to ask a more smarter question without so much unnecessary details, so anyone intend to help can point to the question at once.  Thanks, again~