# Dll used in multiple Applications but different methods

Tags: c#, dll, interface, abstract

C#
Hello there,

I am building a Dll where all my CustomControls are located in(Buttons, a Custom MessageBox etc.). I want to use these controls in multiple Applications. 
The Applications are multilingual.
The problem is that each application has a different way to translate the text.  For example i have a custom button, the button has a property called `KeywordText`: that means i give him a keyword for example "First.Run" and the button translates it in "This is the first time you run this Application".
In one software the text gets translated by calling `Config.Translation["First.Run"];`. In the other applications its handled differently.

My question is, can i create a method in my dll that is called 'TranslateText(string text)'. And then define it in each program and not in the dll itself. For example in the 1. Application i would define it
`public string TranslateText(string text){
     return Config.Translation[text];
}`

And in my CustomButton i would set the text like: `this.Text=TranslateText(keyword);`.
The button should then call the method TranslateText() from the application the button is used in.

I hope you understand what i mean :)

Comment: Yes, that is possible!

Comment: and how? i tried it with an interface and with abstract classes, but neither worked, could you send me a link or explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest change you can do is change your method with virtual keyword

```
public virtual string TranslateText(string text){
   return Config.Translation[text];
}
```

And then in applications where translation logic is different, derive a control from your dll's control, and override the method with different logic.

Or in another approach, you can pass the function as parameter from your calling assembly to your controls dll using the delegate. If you don't know what is function callback see [What is a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139812/what-is-a-callback)

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer, i will take a look at it :)

Comment: yes, i use a static object that i create from a lass with only virtual methods. At the start of my application i override the methods of that object.