# How to create a generic try catch repeated code?

Tags: c#, generics, try-catch

Almost all my codes in C# are something like this:

```
try
{
   response = SomeMethod(requestModel);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  this.logger.Log(ex.MoreDetails());
  response = this.BadRequest();
}
```

the SomeMethod is the only thing that is different, but all the request models inherit some parent model.
Any tips so I don't have to keep repeating this on all my codes? The response also use the same generic model.

Comment: Just have a look at this answer, you should define a base class for that and implement that function. or just a static method with a delegate. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2139878/13583842

Comment: You could write a helper method that takes a `Func<Request>` and do the try catch and logging for you.

Comment: If that is really all there is to all your code then just handle exceptions inside `SomeMethod` and return `BadRequest` if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a method which accepts `Func` as parameter:

```
class Request{} 
class BadRequest:Request{}
class AnotherRequest:Request{}

static Request HandleException(Func<Request> f)
{
    Request result ;
    try
    {
        result = f();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = new BadRequest();
    }
    return result;
}

static AnotherRequest SomeMethod(int i) => new AnotherRequest();
```

And usage:

```
Request result = HandleException(() => SomeMethod(1));
```