# Can I return data from an anonymous callback function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm sure this is simple, but I'm tripping up over a scope issue in Javascript. I'm doing the following:

```
$.get(url, function (data){console.log(data);});
```

This part works fine - I see the string that I want appear in the console. But what I actually want is to take that data variable and place it in a string. Something like this (doesn't work):

```
string = $.get(url, function (data){return data;});
```

This gives `string` a value of `[object XMLHttpRequest]`.

What am I missing?

### Oops

Yes, I'm missing the fact that Ajax is, as the name says, asynchronous. Thanks for giving me the slap on the forehead I needed, everyone.

### Afterword

The reason I wasn't simply working with the results inside the callback function itself is that I actually need to do multiple AJAX requests every few seconds, gather up the data, and append them all to the page when they're all done.

I've now got that working with a little closure function - the requests are done in a loop, and the data is passed to the closure. When the timer goes off, I call the closure function with no arguments, which tells it "append your previous batch of data to the page (the requests are surely complete by now), clear your cache, and prepare to start receiving new data from the AJAX callbacks in my loop."

Which (hopefully) shows that I'm not an idiot after all. :)

Comment: I'm sure there are at least 9000 duplicates of this question.

Comment: @MooGoo, yes there are many duplicates out there and despite this it seems that people still don't get it how AJAX works.

Comment: @Matt Ball - no need for the rant. I was already using Firebug and `console.log()`, as I stated in the question, and I understand that `[object XMLHttpRequest]` is not the actual value, but the string representation of an object. I typed it out that way partly to make my question more searchable for others who hit the same issue. As you can see from the accepted answer, my problem was elsewhere.

Comment: If you're down-voting this question, what you're saying is "this shouldn't be listed here, shouldn't show up on Google, etc." Which would make me happy, since I asked a dumb question, but it increases the chances of it being asked again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) sends an AJAX GET HTTP request and returns immediately meaning that you cannot assign the result to a variable simply because the result is only available in the success callback (the anonymous function you are passing as second argument). In this callback you could call another functions and pass the data as variable. That's just how AJAX works. The `A` stands for asynchronous.

Answer (score 3):

Returning data from the callback function only returns it to the caller of that callback function, which is jQuery, which does nothing with it.

What you can't do is pass that value from the callback function into the assignment in the surrounding function, and the reason you can't do that is because it would be time travel. The `get()` method returns instantly, starting off an HTTP request in the background that will complete later. When it does, the callback function is called, but by that time the `string` has long ago been assigned.

You can't call asynchronous code synchronously, or vice versa. If you want to do something with the result of the HTTP request, you can only do that in a callback function. If you want to provide a function that makes an HTTP request and passes the result back, you have to do it by accepting and calling a callback function yourself:

```
function getThing(callback) {
    ...
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

The alternative is to do the whole lot synchronously, using `async: false`. But that's bad news for everyone, as the web browser hangs up until the request is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax requests are done asynchronously<sup>1</sup>, the last argument of the JQuery's ajax functions is a callback. To answer why your second example doesn't work, you need to understand [async callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047662/what-is-asynccallback). Alternately, this is similar to the observer pattern where the `observable` is the Ajax request and the `observer` is the callback. The steps to perform a request are (roughly) :

1. create an XmlHttpRequest object
2. build the request and send it
3. wait for response
4. receive a response (there are different states there)
5. processing the response
6. Notifying the callback

The argument `data` in the callback arrives at step 6, while the `$.get()` call returns at step 2. So your data is not available. You need to set the data at step 6 in some variable and process it from there.

---

<sup>1</sup> requests can be done synchronously, however the **A** in Ajax stands for *Asynchronous*. One could use `$.get()` to perform a synchronized request, but could not be technically called "Ajax". My point of view.

Answer (score 0):

that data var being passed to your anonymous function is the ajax object itself.  If you want to return the response text from the server, you would do something like this:

```
$.get(url, 
    // data to send
    {
      'foo' : 'bar'
    },
    // receive response
    function(response){
      return response;
    } // response callback function
); // .get()
```

Comment: Returning from the success callback of an AJAX request doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

you could do one of two things:

1 - change your GET to be synchronous with `{async: false }`, you may need to use the $.ajax method to do that.  then assign the variable inside the success callback.

2 - put whatever you have that is using the variable inside the success callback.

```
$.get(url, function (data){
    var string = data;
    useMyString(string);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're trying:

```
var data = $.get(url, function(data){return data;});
// trying to do the stuff you want to do with data
```

This is what you need to do:

```
$.get(url, function(data){
    // do the stuff you want to do with data
});
```